# Trouble Displaying Textures OpenGL ES 1.1

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

I'm working on a simple little game for the iPhone, and I'd like to use textures, however I can't quite seem to get it working...

After some research I found [this page](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/loading-images-opengl-iphone) and [this site](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-6_25.html). Both are great references, and taught me a little bit about textures, however, after loading a texture using either function I can't get the texture displayed, here's what my code looks like:

**Very Simple Texture Display Function** (not working)

```
void drawTexture(GLuint texture, float x, float y, float w, float h)
{
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);

   GLfloat box[] = {x,y+h, x+w,y+h, x,y, x+w,y};
   GLfloat tex[] = {0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1};

   glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
   glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

   glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0,box);
   glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, tex);

   glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);

   glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
   glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

Normally, I'd not create an array every single frame only to display an image, but this is just an example. When I run this function, I get nothing. Blank- no image, nothing (unless of course I'd previously enabled a color array and hadn't disabled it afterwards)

**Second Simple Display Function** (this one uses a quick little class)

```
void draw_rect(RectObject* robj){
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, [robj vertices]);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, [robj colors]);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    if ([robj texture] != -1){
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glClientActiveTexture([robj texture]);

        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, defaultTexCoord);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [robj texture]);
    }

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

This function on the other hand, does change the display, instead of outputting the texture however it outputs a black square...

**Setup Background**

In my init function I'm calling

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_SRC_COLOR);
```

**Two LONG Texture Loading Functions**

```
struct Texture2D LoadImage(NSString* path)
{
    struct Texture2D tex;
    tex.texture = -1;

    // Id for texture 
    GLuint texture;
    // Generate textures
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    // Bind it
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    // Set a few parameters to handle drawing the image
    // at lower and higher sizes than original
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);

    //NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:imagefile.c_str()];
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path ofType:@""];
    NSData *texData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:texData];
    if (image == nil)
        return tex;
    // Get Image size
    GLuint width = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
    GLuint height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    // Allocate memory for image
    void *imageData = malloc( height * width * 4 );
    CGContextRef imgcontext = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                imageData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace,
                                                kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big );
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
    CGContextClearRect( imgcontext,
                   CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ) );
    CGContextTranslateCTM( imgcontext, 0, height - height );
    CGContextDrawImage( imgcontext,
                   CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ), image.CGImage );

    // Generate texture in opengl
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height,
             0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
    // Release context
    CGContextRelease(imgcontext);
    // Free Stuff
    free(imageData);
    [image release];
    [texData release];

    // Create and return texture

    tex.texture=texture;
    tex.width=width;
    tex.height=height;
    return tex;
}



GLuint makeTexture(NSString* path){
    GLuint texture[1]={-1};
    glGenTextures(1, texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);



    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *texData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:texData];
    if (image == nil)
        NSLog(@"Do real error checking here");

    GLuint width = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
    GLuint height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    void *imageData = malloc( height * width * 4 );
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate( imageData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big );
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
    CGContextClearRect( context, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ) );
    CGContextTranslateCTM( context, 0, height - height );
    CGContextDrawImage( context, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ), image.CGImage );

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

    CGContextRelease(context);

    free(imageData);
    [image release];
    [texData release];

    return texture[0];
}
```

If you could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your `draw_rect` function has an error. Don't call `glClientActiveTexture`, it is used for multi-texturing and you don't need it. Calling it with a texture object will either bind some really strange texture unit or, most likely, result in an error.

And in the `drawTexture` function you are actually drawing the triangles in clockwise order. Assuming you didn't flip the y-direction in the projection matrix or something similar, if you have back-face culling enabled your whole geometry will get culled away. Try calling `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)`, although back-face culling should be disabled by default. Or even better, change your vertices to counter-clockwise ordering:

```
box[] = { x,y+h, x,y, x+w,y+h, x+w,y };
```

You also have a mismatch of texture coordinates to vertices in your `drawTexture` function, but this shouldn't cause the texture not to be drawn, but rather just look a bit strange. Considering the changes to counter-clockwise ordering from the last paragraph, the texture coordinates should be:

```
tex[] = { 0.0f,1.0f, 0.0f,0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
```

**EDIT:** Your `draw_rect` function is also messing up the state, because you enable the vertex and color arrays, but then don't disable them again when you are finished with rendering. When you now want to draw something different without a color array (like in `drawTexture`), the color array is still enabled and uses some arbitrary data. So you should add

```
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

right after

```
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

in `draw_rect`.

**EDIT:** And you should also wrap the drawTexture function in a pair of `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` and `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`. You enable texturing in the initialization code, which is wrong. You should set all neccessary state right before rendering, especially such highly object-dependent state like texturing. For example once you call `draw_rect` before `drawTexture`, you end up with disabled texturing, although you enabled it in the initialization code and thought it to be always enabled. Do you see that this is not a good idea?

**EDIT:** I just spotted another error. In `draw_rect` you call `glEnable` and `glDisable` with `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY`, which is wrong. You have to use `glEnableClientState` and `glDisableClientState` for enabling/disabling vertex arrays, like you did int `drawTexture`.

So as a little mid-way conclusion your functions should actually look like:

```
void drawTexture(GLuint texture, float x, float y, float w, float h)
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GLfloat box[] = {x,y+h, x+w,y+h, x,y, x+w,y};
    GLfloat tex[] = {0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1};

    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, tex);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, box);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

void draw_rect(RectObject* robj)
{
    if ([robj texture] != -1)
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [robj texture]);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, defaultTexCoord);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }

    glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, [robj colors]);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, [robj vertices]);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    if ([robj texture] != -1)
    {
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response- I changed my vertices to a counter-clockwise order, but no dice... Disabling back-face culling also didn't seem to affect the problem.. So it seems to me the problem is not now in the drawing functions but rather somewhere else in my code, would you lean in that direction as well?

Comment: @ultifinitus Have you also made the proposed change to `draw_rect` (remove the call to `glClientActiveTexture`? Does this draw the texture? And have you made sure the rectangle is actually visible in your current view and projection setup?

Comment: Yes, and yes- interestingly, I removed `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);`(and disable) from the `draw_rect` function and added `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` to the `drawTexture` function. Now the second function is working just as expected, the image is actually displayed!! But the other is not. Thank you so much for your help, if you'll include those findings in your answer, that would be great!

Comment: @ultifinitus Why did you remove the enable/disable of the texCoord array? This shouldn't work, because now you don't have valid texture coordinates, or you are now using the ones from the `drawTexture` function accidentally, which is even more wrong.

Comment: @ultifinitus And you should also disable the vertex and color arrays before returning from `draw_rect`.

Comment: @ultifinitus Are you sure your `defaultTexCoord` array contains valid data? Ah, I got it, will update my answer.

Comment: 1. I see- well that is definitely a problem.  
2. Done and done.  
3. DefaultTexCoord holds `{ 0.0f,1.0f, 0.0f,0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };`

Comment: @ultifinitus Look at my updated answer. Try the provided versions of your functions, which include fixes for all the possible errors I found in your code that far.

Comment: instead of having `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)` I now have `glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);` (I just ran through with glGetError() and found that was wrong) I changed the second function to use a third function that draws a texture based on coordinates. That works, I am now having a problem with textures larger in size than 32x32, strange for sure, I'll scour my code, and continue trying to fix the problem, and let you know what I find.

Comment: @ultifinitus That (the `glEnableClientState` thing) is also what I told you in my answer. Have you read it already?

Comment: ops, didn't see your comment. Thank you so much for your help.  Alright, I swapped the functions, and it works exactly as expected (same problem with the larger textures, I'm assuming I'm doing something else wrong- I'll try to snoop it out)

Comment: Yes, I have read your extended answer. Haha, I noticed you had said the clientState thing directly after I had implemented it.

Comment: The texture issue seems to be because the large textures are not 2^x so I'll just change my textures to be powers of two and everything is golden.

Answer (score 1):

If one of the textures work and the other not, could it be a problem with the texture file ?
Dimensions sometimes can trick you, try to use the same file (the one working) on both textures and see if that solved. If it does it's a problem with the texture file.

Comment: It is indeed, it just so happens that its dimensions have to be a power of 2 (or at least those are the only ones that have worked so far)

Answer (score 0):

The fun does work.

```
void drawTexture(GLuint texture, float x, float y, float w, float h)
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GLfloat box[] = {x,y+h, x+w,y+h, x,y, x+w,y};
    GLfloat tex[] = {0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1};

    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, tex);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, box);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

but we should relate to the right coordinate for texture. wo should change the code

form

```
GLfloat box[] = {x,y+h, x+w,y+h, x,y, x+w,y};
GLfloat tex[] = {0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1};
```

to

```
GLfloat box[] = {x,y+h, x+w,y+h, x,y, x+w,y};
GLfloat tex[] = { 0.0f,1.0f,  1.0f,1.0f, 0.0f,0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
```

Thanks stackoverflow. Thanks your help.
Good luck!